# Azure SQL metric

Tags: azure, metrics, azure-sql

I am not able to find few SQL metrics in Azure. Can anyone help in how to set metrics for below topics.

1)Under utilized capacity

2)Number of databases outside of pool

3)Scale up

4)Connection timeout

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for some very different things here, so these would need to come from different places.

1. Under Utilized Capacity - you should be looking at metrics like CPU, Memory or DTU use on your SQL databases to see what capacity is being used. These are all available from Azure Monitor
2. Number of databases outside of pool - not entirely clear what you want here, but I am guessing you want to see SQL database that are not in an elastic pool? If so then you can use Azure Resource Explore to query for databases not in an elastic pool
3. Scale up - again not sure what you are looking for. If you want to know when you need to scale your DB up, then again look at Azure Monitor for metrics on CPU, Memory etc.
4. Connection Timeout - This is really a client side thing, not something you can measure from SQL